# Hash method get on ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to get some values for a hash but, I don't know how can I do it!
My data:

```
data = {
          name: "Pedro Álvares",
          age: 35,
          sensitive_data: {
            cpf_cnpj=>27046645678, 
            fantasy_name: "I have the power"
            }
        }
```

I search for ruby methods and find the method **values_at**, but this method gets only the first_data like **name, age**.
If I use:

```
name = data.values_at(:name)
```

the field returned is **Pedro Álvares**
but if I try use:

```
fantasy_name = data.values_at(:fantasy_name)
```

the data returned is **nil**.

How can I get the field without using **data[:sensitive_data][:fantasy_name]**?

Comment: Why don't you want to use nested hash access with bracket notation? (Noting that you could do the same thing with chained "values_at"?) What aren't you telling us?

Comment: Ruby will assume `cpf_cnpj` is a method but will not be able to find it. Perhaps you mean it to be a string or a symbol, in which case it needs quotes or a colon. My edit was merely to remove the rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question.

Comment: @DaveNewton, my question is because if I had a lot of nested fields the code grew up. In the example, the code is short, but in my real case, I have a lot of nested fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CarySwoveland for your answer and edit!

Comment: @EricGomes I think if you have deeply-nested fields with arbitrary keys you might want to pull some of the logic out into something else, or restructure when/how you're looking at the data. What makes the most sense is pretty context-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the nested value by [dig](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig) method:

```rb
data.dig(:sensitive_data, :fantasy_name) # => "I have the power"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you know the correct structure of the hash you should write:

```
data[:sensitive_data][:fantasy_name]
  #=> "I have the power"
```

You should not use `dig` here. Why? Suppose you accidently wrote

```
data.dig(:sesnitive_data, :fantasy_name)
```

The would return `nil` (because `data` has no key `:sesnitive`). Depending on the context the error might not surface until sometime later, making debugging more difficult than is necessary.

By contrast, if you wrote

```
data[:sesnitive_data][:fantasy_name]
```

`data[:sesnitive_data]` would return `nil` (because `data` has no key `:sesnitive_data`) and then `nil[:sesnitive_data]` would raise an exception, informing you that `nil` has no method `[]`. That is precisely what you want to happen: you want to be notified of the error immediately, and have the reason for it it pinpointed, so you can easily correct your code.

[Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig), [Array#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-dig) and [Struct#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Struct.html#method-i-dig) (which call each other) have their uses (when you do not know the structures of objects in advance--a hash's keys, for example), but those methods should not be used when an object's structure is known.

Comment: If you want errors for missing keys, there's `fetch` which raises a `KeyError` right away.

Comment: @Stefan, good point, something I was not aware of. Nor did I know `fetch` could take a block; I always thought of it in its third form, of taking a default value as an argument.